# How to disable VSCode Workbench List Keyboard navigation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The Jan 2019 update for VSCode added filtering Workbench files on keyboard input. It has overwritten my file/folder creation shortcuts (I use keys a/A) on Workbench. There is no disable option available. I see only simple, highlight and filter.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_workbench

I generally use Ctrl + P for searching files. So I don't need it.

Is there a way to disable this feature or re-enable my a/A shortcuts to create file/folder?

Comment: what's `on Workbench`, is workbench you said a vscode extension ?

Comment: @pwxcoo, not extension, VSCode file explorer side bar. The Gif I attached in question shows the animation of the feature, which I want disabled.